# Dictionary of Words as keys and the Sentences it appears in as values

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a text which I split into a list of unique words using set. I also have split the text into a list of sentences. I then split that list of sentences into a list of lists (of the words in each sentence / maybe I don't need to do the last part)

```
text = 'i was hungry. i got food. now i am not hungry i am full'

sents = ['i was hungry', 'i got food', 'now i am', 'not hungry i am full']

words = ['i', 'was', 'hungry', 'got', 'food', 'now', 'not', 'am', 'full']

split_sents = [['i', 'was', 'hungry'], ['i', 'got', 'food'], ['now', 'i', 'am', 'not','hungry','i','am','full']]
```

I want to write a loop or a list comprehension that makes a dictionary where each word in words is a key and if the word appears in a sentence each sentence is captured as a list value so I can then get some statistics like the count of sentences but also the average length of the sentences for each word...so far I have the following but it's not right.

```
word_freq = {}
for sent in split_sents:
  for word in words:
    if word in sent:
      word_freq[word] += sent
    else:
      word_freq[word] = sent
```

it returns a dictionary of word keys and empty values. Ideally, I'd like to do it without collections/counter though any solution is appriciated. I'm sure this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the right solution so feel free to link and close if you link to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using list and dictionary comprehension

**Code:**

```
text = 'i was hungry. i got food. now i am not hungry i am full'

sents = ['i was hungry', 'i got food', 'now i am', 'not hungry i am full']

words = ['i', 'was', 'hungry', 'got', 'food', 'now', 'not', 'am', 'full']


word_freq = {w:[s for s in sents if w in s.split()] for w in words }

print(word_freq)
```

**Output:**

```
{
'i': ['i was hungry', 'i got food', 'now i am', 'not hungry i am full'], 
'was': ['i was hungry'], '
hungry': ['i was hungry', 'not hungry i am full'], 
'got': ['i got food'], 
'food': ['i got food'], 
'now': ['now i am'], 
'not': ['not hungry i am full'], 
'am': ['now i am', 'not hungry i am full'], 
'full': ['not hungry i am full']
}
```

**Or if you want output sentences as list of words:**

```
word_freq = {w:[s.split() for s in sents if w in s.split()] for w in words }
```

**Output:**

```
{
'i': [['i', 'was', 'hungry'], ['i', 'got', 'food'], ['now', 'i', 'am'], ['not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']], 
'was': [['i', 'was', 'hungry']], 
'hungry': [['i', 'was', 'hungry'], ['not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']], 
'got': [['i', 'got', 'food']], 
'food': [['i', 'got', 'food']], 
'now': [['now', 'i', 'am']], 
'not': [['not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']], 
'am': [['now', 'i', 'am'], ['not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']], 
'full': [['not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word_freq = {}
for word in set(words):
     word_freq[word] = list()

for sent in split_sents:
     for word in words:
     if word in sent:
          word_freq[word].append(sent)

print(word_freq)

=================================================================

{'am': [['now', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']],
 'food': [['i', 'got', 'food']],
 'full': [['now', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']],
 'got': [['i', 'got', 'food']],
 'hungry': [['i', 'was', 'hungry'],
            ['now', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']],
 'i': [['i', 'was', 'hungry'],
       ['i', 'got', 'food'],
       ['now', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']],
 'not': [['now', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']],
 'now': [['now', 'i', 'am', 'not', 'hungry', 'i', 'am', 'full']],
 'was': [['i', 'was', 'hungry']]}
```

Comment: thank you @Abhi_J is that a list comprehension inside a dictionary comprehension?  and thanks Daniel111 for the solution also.